# No puedo acceder a los datos enviados por post desde servicio externo

Tags: php, laravel, api

estoy tratando de recibir los datos de una API por POST en formato JSON.
En el ejemplo que tienen en la documentación, funciona correctamente. Pero en laravel no se reciben los datos. Desde Postman sí he podido.

Ejemplo de la API que **sí** funciona.

```
$calls = json_decode($_POST["calls"], true);

foreach($calls as $call){
   foreach($call as $value) {
      $linecall = $linecall. ";" .$value;
   }
   $linecall = $linecall."\n";
}
```

En cambio, en laravel no funciona con el siguiente código:

```
public function index(Request $request){

    $calls = json_decode($request->input('calls'), true);

    foreach ($calls as $call => $data) {
        Log::info('---------------CALL-----------------------');
        Log::info('Stop date ' . $data['stopdate']);
        Log::info('Duration ' . $data['duration']);
        Log::info('DST ' . $data['dst']);
        Log::info('SRC ' . $data['src']);
        Log::info('-------------END CALL---------------------');
    }
}
```

El log devuelve el siguiente error.

```
ErrorException: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Archivo de rutas:

```
Route::any('/ApiTest', 'ApiTestController@index');
```

He probado distintas variantes de este código pero creo que no estoy procesando los datos de manera correcta. La entrada "calls" siempre está vacía desde laravel.

He preguntado a soporte y me han dicho que no lleva cabeceras de ningún tipo.

Gracias de antemano.

Dejo el enlace a la documentación de la api por si alguien saca algo en claro que yo no veo.
[https://apidoc.netelip.com/v1/voice/#informe-de-llamadas][1]

---

#SOLUCIÓN#

Establecer la ruta de destino sin / de lo contrario la petición aparece vacía.

*Sí funciona*
`https://ejemplo.com/api/destino`

*No funciona*
`https://ejemplo.com/api/destino/`

Comment: Me parece que el error puede estar en como se envían los datos desde el otro lado, puedes intentar también sin hacer `json_decode()`; y en los **headers** de la solicitud debería de estar el `Content-Type: application/json` sino, por experiencia los datos siempre llegaran vacíos

Comment: Puedes ejecutar `print_r($calls);` antes del foreach y mostrarnos el resultado

Comment: Este es el resultado de print_r($calls) y print_r($request->input('calls))

`[2021-07-05 18:03:55] local.INFO: 1`
`[2021-07-05 18:03:55] local.INFO: 1`

Comment: @Josbert, creo que la opción de que modifiquen las cabeceras es casi imposible. Aún así voy a ver que me dicen.

Comment: Parece que los datos no te están llegando del todo vacíos, por tu `print_r($calls);` prueba tal vez con un `dd($calls);` y observaras un poco mejor

Comment: @Josbert, no puedo usar el log con dd(), detiene la ejecución y no registra nada. Alguna otra idea?

Comment: Hola, pensando un poco en tu problema el día de ayer, se me ocurre algo que tal vez te funcione. Trata de obtener el crudo de la solicitud así `$calls = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);` si esto no te funciona o te arroja un error agrega esto antes de eso: `$request = Request::instance();` a travez de la *Facade* Request

Comment: Hola @Josbert, disculpa mi tardanza en contestar. Devuelve el mismo error y los resultados son los mismos. Podría ser cosa de CORS? Aunque no me guste, voy a tener que usar un subdominio para hacer de puente y conectar con laravel de otra forma.

Comment: @GuillermoAC no creo que sean problemas de **cors**, pero siendo eso puedes fácilmente configurar lo en *Laravel*, `config/cors.php`

Comment: Bueno, parece que ya está solucionado.

Tras investigar mucho de casualidad encontré un post de alguien que comentaba que las rutas de destino no podían terminar en /. 

cambié:
`https:://domino.com/api/ruta/` 
por 
`https:://domino.com/api/ruta`

y ya pude acceder a los datos con:

`json_decode($request->calls, true);`

Muchas gracias por la ayuda de todas maneras.